# PDFbox Could not find font: /Helv

Tags: java, pdfbox

I try to add form fields to existing PDF file but the following error appears `PDFbox Could not find font: /Helv`

My code in Java has the following view:

```
        PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
        PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdf.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
        PDPage page = pdf.getPage(0);

        PDTextField textBox = new PDTextField(acroForm);
        textBox.setPartialName("SampleField");
        acroForm.getFields().add(textBox);
        PDAnnotationWidget widget = textBox.getWidgets().get(0);
        PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        widget.setRectangle(rect);
        widget.setPage(page);
        widget.setAppearance(acroForm.getFields().get(0).getWidgets().get(0).getAppearance());

        widget.setPrinted(false);

        page.getAnnotations().add(widget);

        acroForm.refreshAppearances();
        acroForm.flatten();
        pdf.save(outputStream);
        pdf.close();
```

Do you have any ideas why the exception appears?

There is top of stack trace

```
java.io.IOException: Could not find font: /Helv
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.processSetFont(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:179)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.processOperator(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:132)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.processAppearanceStringOperators(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:108)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.<init>(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:86)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDVariableText.getDefaultAppearanceString(PDVariableText.java:93)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.<init>(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:100)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField.constructAppearances(PDTextField.java:262)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm.refreshAppearances(PDAcroForm.java:368)
at com.workjam.service.impl.PDFService.fillForm(PDFService.java:85)
```

Here is the link for PDF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2--NSDOiujoR3hOZFYteUl2UE0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Which pdfbox version do you use ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your new text field doesn't have a default appearance, so PDFBox makes one for you (`/Helv 0 Tf 0 g`).

Solution 1: get it from the field you're using (this will not work with every PDF because you're making several assumptions, i.e. that there is a field and that it is a text field)

```
textBox.setDefaultAppearance(((PDTextField)acroForm.getFields().get(0)).getDefaultAppearance());
```

Solution 2: initialize the default resources:

```
PDResources resources = new PDResources();
resources.put(COSName.getPDFName("Helv"), PDType1Font.HELVETICA);
acroForm.setDefaultResources(resources);
```

See also the [CreateSimpleForm.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/CreateSimpleForm.java?view=markup) example from the source code download.

Update: this has been fixed in 2.0.8, see issue [PDFBOX-3943](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3943).

Comment: You were slightly faster posting your answer... ;) Nonetheless, I used your solution 1 myself but was taken aback a little because in the saved file the **Fields** array in the **AcroForm** dictionary was missing. Might there be another issue?

Comment: @mkl that's because of the flattening he does. That one empties the field array.

Comment: Arg! When seeing the emptied fields, I had completely forgotten about that detail...

Answer (score 1):

The cause is a combination of you and the source PDF not providing a default appearance for the text field and PDFBox providing defaults inconsequentially.

#### The default appearance

According to the specification, each field containing variable text (e.g. your text field) must have a **DA** default appearance value:

> **DA**
>   string
>   **(Required; inheritable)** The default appearance string containing a sequence of valid page-content graphics or text state operators that define such properties as the field’s text size and colour.
>
> *(ISO 32000-1, Table 222 – Additional entries common to all fields containing variable text)*

In addition to parent fields in the field tree, the **DA** value can also be inherited from the **AcroForm** dictionary:

> **DA**
>   string
>   *(Optional)* A document-wide default value for the DA attribute of variable text fields (see 12.7.3.3, “Variable Text”).
>
> *(ISO 32000-1, Table 218 – Entries in the interactive form dictionary)*

#### In your PDF

You don't provide a default appearance, and your PDF does not have a default in the **AcroForm** dictionary.

Thus, strictly speaking, it is not valid at the moment you call `acroForm.refreshAppearances()`. So PDFBox could reject that call due to missing information.

It works differently, though, as PDFBox provides defaults for certain **AcroForm** dictionary entries if they are not present, in particular

```
final String adobeDefaultAppearanceString = "/Helv 0 Tf 0 g ";

// DA entry is required
if (getDefaultAppearance().length() == 0)
{
    setDefaultAppearance(adobeDefaultAppearanceString);
}
```

Unfortunately, though, PDFBox does not ensure that the font **Helv** used here is in the default resources unless they are also missing completely.

#### Solutions

I just saw Tilman wrote an answer here, too. You can find solutions to your issue there.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that the case is missing in `PDAcroForm.verifyOrCreateDefaults()` which attempts to prevent problems like this one. I'll fix that tonight.