# Why are Form Fields set with PDFBox(2.0.11) not being displayed?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox 2.0.11 to open a PDF Form and pulling out the values. This works as expected. When I try to set a value it appears to work. When I open the PDF the value is not displayed. If I click in the field, the value is then displayed as set, but then disappears again when I click out of the field.

This seems to be a common issue, but none of the fixes I've seen seem to work.

```
if(file.exists())
    {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
        doc.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
        PDDocumentCatalog catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDAcroForm form = catalog.getAcroForm();

        // Add Font
        PDResources resources = new PDResources();
        resources.put(COSName.getPDFName("Helv"), PDType1Font.HELVETICA);
        form.setDefaultResources(resources);
        // End Add Font

        form.setNeedAppearances(false);
        List<PDField> fields = form.getFields();

        for (Object field : fields) 
        {
            if (field instanceof PDTextField) {
                PDTextField pdTextbox = (PDTextField) field;
                System.out.println("PDTextBox " + pdTextbox.getFullyQualifiedName() + " " + pdTextbox.getValue());

                if(pdTextbox.getFullyQualifiedName().equalsIgnoreCase("a3_5"))
                {
                    try {
                        pdTextbox.getWidgets().get(0).setHidden(false);
                        pdTextbox.setValue("5500");
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(field);
                System.out.print(" = ");
                System.out.print(field.getClass());
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        doc.save("..._MINE_UPDATE.pdf");
        doc.close();
    }
```

Stack Trace

```
java.io.IOException: Could not find font: /Helvetica
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.processSetFont(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:179)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.processOperator(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:132)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.processAppearanceStringOperators(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:108)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.<init>(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:86)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDVariableText.getDefaultAppearanceString(PDVariableText.java:93)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.<init>(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:100)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField.constructAppearances(PDTextField.java:262)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTerminalField.applyChange(PDTerminalField.java:228)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField.setValue(PDTextField.java:218)
at com.controller.TestPDFBox.loadData(TestPDFBox.java:87)
```

Skipped for loop

```
for (COSName fontResourceName : widgetResources.getFontNames())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (acroFormResources.getFont(fontResourceName) == null)
                    {
                        LOG.debug("Adding font resource " + fontResourceName + " from widget to AcroForm");
                        acroFormResources.put(fontResourceName, widgetResources.getFont(fontResourceName));
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    LOG.warn("Unable to match field level font with AcroForm font");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please try removing `form.setNeedAppearances(true);` or set it to false.

Comment: No, that didn't work. The value is being set, and if I click into the field I see it, but as soon as it loses focus it hides again.

Comment: Please share the file. If you can't share the file, then you'll have to debug in PDFBox: find out whether `PDTextfield.constructAppearances()` is hit and what happens within, i.e. whether an appearance is created in AppearanceGeneratorHelper.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr It does look to be some kind of problem with the form. In 'PDTextfield.constructAppearances()' the last line, 'apHelper.setAppearanceValue(getValue());' doesn't ever get called, but there isn't any console output that would explain why. I've stepped through the process and it just seems to skip it. I followed the constructor for 'PDDefaultAppearanceString' as that's the last part of the constructor for 'AppearanceGeneratorHelper' but it doesn't seem to be failing anywhere. The PDF in question is locked, but I'm not sure if that is the cause or not.

Comment: Re the "it just seems to skip it" - from my experience, that could be an exception. The `PDDefaultAppearanceString` constructor can throw two exceptions. Please put breakpoints there. Also make sure to improve `catch(Exception e){
                        // Do nothing
                    }`. You should at least put `e.printStackTrace()` there.

Comment: One possible problem I see with your code is that you are overwriting the default resources, instead of just adding the Helvetica font to a (possibly) existing resources. Another thing to do is to check whether the acroform has a /DA entry. (defaultAppearance).

Comment: Great call on the stack trace. It was getting thrown all the way up and I was missing it. The error is `java.io.IOException: Could not find font: /Helvetica` but it actually looks like you fixed that issue. [PDFBOX-3942] (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3943)  This error is thrown whether or not I explicitly set the default resource.

Comment: That one is fixed in 2.0.11 (are you really using 2.0.11 ?). Please edit your question and include the stack trace. I wonder if there is more in your actual code… PDFBox is missing "/Helvetica" and you added "/Helv", but don't use it in the code shown.

Comment: Do I need to specify the font for each field I update if the default is set on the form?

I've updated the question to how my code looks now. This is the full code. The most basic get/set values. I am using 2.0.11. I'm receiving the same exception with, or without the `Add Font` section. That code I pulled from one of your answers (Solution 2) to a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433388/pdfbox-could-not-find-font-helv).

Comment: No, normally there is no need to bother about the fonts. I suspect that there is a flaw in your PDF. Did you create it yourself, or somebody in the team? Please add "Helvetica" to the default resources: `resources.put(COSName.getPDFName("Helvetica"), PDType1Font.HELVETICA);` and do not replace the default resources (check if it exists), and only call `new PDResources` if it doesn't.

Comment: Good news is the exception went away. Bad news the value is still hidden unless you click into the field, and then disappears again when you click out. I also noticed that the value isn't being returned with `pdTextbox.getValue()` I verified no XFA as well.

Comment: Then please do the debugging again (third comment from the top) to find out whether the appearance stream is set. If you have some understanding about fields + widgets + structures in a PDF, try looking at the file with PDFDebugger and find the field.

Comment: The only thing that immediately jumps out at me is the second for loop (copied into the question above) is skipped over in `AppearanceGeneratorHelper.validateAndEnsureAcroFormResources()` like widgetResources.getFontNames() is empty.

Comment: I don't see this as a problem, as long as there's something in the default resources. And that is collected earlier in that method.

Comment: It goes through setAppearanceValue just fine. It happily sets a defaultAppearance at the end.

Comment: The string parameter in `setAppearanceValue` does it have the correct value?

Comment: It does. However, I think I owe you a monetary payment. After extensive testing with other PDF's I figured out the issue. Once a PDF is opened in macOS's default viewer `Preview` it pretty much tanks the document (as of High Sierra 10.13.2). A used an adobe install to verify and everything works correctly.

Comment: Does this mean this matter is now moot? Anyway, most important thing to remember is never catch an exception and do nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Tilman Hausherr for helping me get to an answer that ultimately stemmed from a quirk with MacOSX's Preview application.

Preview for some reason strips out functionality that also causes you to be unable to set values correctly in the PDF.

The code above works correctly, although I did make a change to the `Add Font` section to the following.

```
// Add Font
PDResources resources = form.getDefaultResources();
if(resources == null)
{
    resources = new PDResources();
}
resources.put(COSName.getPDFName("Helvetica"), PDType1Font.HELVETICA);
if(form.getDefaultResources() == null)
{
    form.setDefaultResources(resources);
}
// End Add Font
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it is not obvious: Don't create / edit / save your template pdf with Mac's Preview to use with PDFBox.

I ran into the same issue and had to re-create the PDF in Acrobat Pro. With this PDF the above code worked perfectly fine.