# Added font not loading correct pdfbox for acroform

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to embed the fonts using the following code,
which is based on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46446879/3423324) and [PDFBOX-2661](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2661?focusedCommentId=14305037&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-14305037):

The font to embed as alternative to Helvetica is [DejaVuSans](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/DejaVu-Sans).

```java
// given: PDDocument document, PDAcroForm acroForm

InputStream font_file = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("DejaVuSans.ttf");
font = PDType0Font.load(document, font_file);
if (font_file != null) {
    font_file.close();
}
System.err.println("Embedded font 'DejaVuSans.ttf' loaded.");

PDResources resources = acroForm.getDefaultResources();
if (resources == null) {
    resources = new PDResources();
}

resources.put(COSName.getPDFName("Helv"), font);
resources.put(COSName.getPDFName("Helvetica"), font);
// Also use "DejaVuSans.ttf" for "HeBo", "HelveticaBold" and "Helvetica-Bold" in a similar way, but this is left out to keep this short.

acroForm.setDefaultResources(resources);

// let pdfbox handle refreshing the values, now that all the fonts should be there.
acroForm.refreshAppearances();
```

However in `acroForm.refreshAppearances()`, it results in a lot of `Using fallback font LiberationSans for CID-keyed TrueType font DejaVuSans`. Debugging it a bit, down there in `createDescendantFont` it tries to load (in `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2`'s `findFontOrSubstitute`) the font file "DejaVuSans" from the filesystem again, instead of using the provided resource. As it is provided in the JAR file instead of from the normal filesystem (system's fonts) is not found, resulting in the fallback font to be used.

**How can I make it recognise and load the font correctly?**

What I already tried:

I tried extending the font loading mechanism, but as everything is private and/or final, I had to stop after I already copied about 10 files unchanged from the original code just to be able to access them; that must be possible in a different way.

Direct writes to the `ContentStream` seem to use a different way (`contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize)`), so that is not affected.

Comment: Please share the PDF to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @mlk https://pdfhost.io/v/Oh9~qVoG5_sample5pdf.pdf

Comment: Your example PDF is a bit weird, all the text fields have a default appearance of `/Helvetica 12 Tf 0 g` but there is no definition of a *Helvetica* font resource. Strictly speaking, therefore, it is broken to start with. Your code, though, kind of fixes this issue by adding a *Helvetica* font default resource. I'll later have a look what happens. My assumption would be that one probably has to remove the current appearances to make `refreshAppearances` properly use the default resources for refreshing.

Answer (score 2):

The current AcroForm form field refreshing mechanism in PDFBox is not really usable in combination with fonts yet to be subsetted.

The cause is that whenever a font is used for refreshing an appearance, it is retrieved from some resources dictionary. In those resource dictionaries, though, there is not your original `PDType0Font` but only a preliminary version of the PDF objects backing your `PDType0Font`. But these PDF objects don't know that they back a font that eventually shall be subsetted, so retrieval of that font generates a new, different `PDType0Font` object which claims to be non-embedded. So it also is not informed about glyphs to eventually embed.

This also is the reason why the `PDType0Font.load` method you use is documented (JavaDoc comments) with the hint ***If you are loading a font for AcroForm, then use the 3-parameter constructor instead***:

```java
/**
 * Loads a TTF to be embedded and subset into a document as a Type 0 font. If you are loading a
 * font for AcroForm, then use the 3-parameter constructor instead.
 *
 * @param doc The PDF document that will hold the embedded font.
 * @param input An input stream of a TrueType font. It will be closed before returning.
 * @return A Type0 font with a CIDFontType2 descendant.
 * @throws IOException If there is an error reading the font stream.
 */
public static PDType0Font load(PDDocument doc, InputStream input) throws IOException
```

And the 3-parameter constructor in its documentation tells you not to use subsetting for fonts for AcroForm usage:

```java
/**
 * Loads a TTF to be embedded into a document as a Type 0 font.
 *
 * @param doc The PDF document that will hold the embedded font.
 * @param input An input stream of a TrueType font. It will be closed before returning.
 * @param embedSubset True if the font will be subset before embedding. Set this to false when
 * creating a font for AcroForm.
 * @return A Type0 font with a CIDFontType2 descendant.
 * @throws IOException If there is an error reading the font stream.
 */
public static PDType0Font load(PDDocument doc, InputStream input, boolean embedSubset)
        throws IOException
```

But even using that 3 parameter constructor with `embedSubset` set to `false` does not render a good result. At first glance the rendered fields look ok:

[image: screen shot]

But as soon as you click into them, something weird happens:

[image: screen shot]

@Tilman, there probably still is something to fix here.

---

The underlying problem with the subset embedded font can also occur in other contexts, e.g.:

```java
try (   PDDocument pdDocument = new PDDocument();
        InputStream font_file = [...]    ) {
    PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(pdDocument, font_file);

    PDResources pdResources = new PDResources();
    COSName name = pdResources.add(font);
    PDPage pdPage = new PDPage();
    pdPage.setResources(pdResources);
    pdDocument.addPage(pdPage);

    try (   PDPageContentStream canvas = new PDPageContentStream(pdDocument, pdPage)    ) {
        canvas.setFont(pdResources.getFont(name), 12);
        canvas.beginText();
        canvas.newLineAtOffset(30, 700);
        canvas.showText("Some test text.");
        canvas.endText();
    }

    pdDocument.save("sampleOfType0Issue.pdf");
}
```

*([RefreshAppearances](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/RefreshAppearances.java#L106) test `testIllustrateType0Issue`)*

Comment: The reason I am trying to set fonts of the Form f ields is that the Helvetica font does not allow some unicode characters which are needed. This seem to related to the list of characters the default fonts are required to implement (Appendix D in the pdf spec) as those causing failure when filling in with xfdf data.

Comment: What *might* work is adding a font in a first step that contains all glyphs you may require, and after saving and reloading the PDF using that font to do as you tried.

Comment: Do I somehow have to manually specify those glyphs, or would it automatically include all of the ones which are in the font?

Comment: That depends on how you add it.

Comment: Trying to add a really popular common free font

`Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: 'loca' table is mandatory; this an OpenType CFF font, but we expected a TrueType font here`

Myriad Pro Regular.ttf

Comment: Consider converting the font format as indicated in the exception message.