# How to use TTF font with PDFBox AcroForm and then flatten document?

Tags: java, pdfbox, truetype, pdf-form, acrofields

I have been trying to make a fillable PDF file with LibreOffice Writer 7.2.2.2. Here is how the document looks like:
[image]
All fields right of the vertical lines are form textboxes, each one having its own name(tbxOrderId, tbxFullName...). Each textbox uses **SF Pro Text Light** as font. Only the one on the bottom right(tbxTotal) - `Total €123.00` has **Oswald Regular**. The document looks alright when I fill these fields with LibreOffice Writer.

Below this are my export settings. I chose `Archive PDF A-2b` in order to embed the fonts into the document.
[image]

Here is the output when I run `pdffonts` to the exported PDF file.
[image]

However, when I run the following code which just changes the values of `tbxOrderId` and `tbxTotal`, the output PDF document is missing these fonts.

```
public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            PDDocument pDDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("/media/stoyank/Elements/Java/tmp/Receipt.pdf"));
            PDAcroForm pDAcroForm = pDDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

            PDField field = pDAcroForm.getField("tbxOrderId");
            field.setValue("192753");
            field = pDAcroForm.getField("tbxTotal");
            field.setValue("Total: €192.00");

            pDAcroForm.flatten();
            pDDocument.save("/media/stoyank/Elements/Java/tmp/output.pdf");
            pDDocument.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how the output document looks like:
[image]

I tried to add the font manually by referring to [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65701597/added-font-not-loading-correct-pdfbox-for-acroform), but still no success:

```
PDDocument pDDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("/media/stoyank/Elements/Java/tmp/Receipt.pdf"));
PDAcroForm pDAcroForm = pDDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

InputStream font_file = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("Oswald-Regular.ttf");
PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(pDDocument, font_file, false);
if (font_file != null) font_file.close();

PDResources resources = pDAcroForm.getDefaultResources();
if (resources == null) resources = new PDResources();

resources.put(COSName.getPDFName("Oswald-Regular"), font);
pDAcroForm.setDefaultResources(resources);
pDAcroForm.refreshAppearances();

PDField field = pDAcroForm.getField("tbxOrderId");
field.setValue("192753");
field = pDAcroForm.getField("tbxTotal");
field.setValue("Total: €192.00");

pDAcroForm.flatten();
pDDocument.save("/media/stoyank/Elements/Java/tmp/output.pdf");
pDDocument.close();
```

After I write into these textbox fields, I want to flatten the document.

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

**System: Ubuntu 20.04**

Also, [here is a link](https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20211109Oz7JYZ2p) to the ODT file that I then export to a PDF and the exported PDF.

Comment: I think you also need to call setDefaultAppearance so that it uses the new (not subsetted) font. See the `CreateSimpleFormWithEmbeddedFont.java` example. Note that the font name is not "Oswald-Regular", it's what you get back from resources.add(). (not resources.put())

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Checked out the `CreateSimpleFormWithEmbeddedFont.java` file and applied everything. Still no success. The output is gibberish. I also get `WARNING: Using fallback font LiberationSans for CID-keyed TrueType font Oswald-Regular`. Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/51huv5Jm

Comment: @TilmanHausherr published the project on GitHub. Here is the link: https://github.com/stoyanK7/pdfbox-stackoverflow-question

Answer (score 0):

Your file doesn't have correct appearance streams for the fields, this is a bug from the software that created the PDF. Call `pDAcroForm.refreshAppearances();` as early as possible.

The code in pastebin is fine (it is based on `CreateSimpleFormWithEmbeddedFont.java` example), except that you should keep the default resources and not start with empty resources. So your code should look like this:

```
pDAcroForm.refreshAppearances();

PDType0Font formFont = PDType0Font.load(pDDocument, ...input stream..., false);

PDResources resources = pDAcroForm.getDefaultResources();
if (resources == null)
{
    resources = new PDResources();
    pDAcroForm.setDefaultResources(resources);
}

final String fontName = resources.add(formFont).getName();

// Acrobat sets the font size on the form level to be
// auto sized as default. This is done by setting the font size to '0'
String defaultAppearanceString = "/" + fontName + " 0 Tf 0 g";

PDTextField field = (PDTextField) (pDAcroForm.getField("tbxTotal"));
field.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearanceString);
field.setValue("Total: €192.00");
```

[image]

Comment: Still getting gibberish even after following your advice: https://imgur.com/a/JkaZXwD . Code: https://pastebin.com/TAJiHRTU

Comment: Can you try loading the font from a file? It might be a resource filtering problem. (I didn't use resources) My result file is here: filedropper.com/6PRv1DY0  Upload your result file, or look at the files with PDFDebugger to see if there is a difference.

Comment: Tried loading it from a file using ```new File()```. Method ```PDType0Font.load()``` cannot take in a third argument when using ```File``` type as second argument though. Still, same result - https://github.com/stoyanK7/pdfbox-stackoverflow-question/blob/main/tmp/output.pdf

Comment: I used FileInputStream so the third parameter is supported. In your file, the font isn't embedded for some reason. Were there any log messages while your code was running?

Comment: Used ```FileInputStream``` too. Same result. The only log message I get is  ```Nov 14, 2021 6:32:24 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
WARNING: Using fallback font LiberationSans for CID-keyed TrueType font Oswald-Regular```. It repeats 4 times.

Comment: Please single-step to find out when is the first time it happens. Also make sure you're really using 2.0.24 (do a clean build, delete old versions from your class path)